# How do I change color's hue, saturation, or value in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, colors

Suppose I have a Color object in Flutter that I want to change its Hue or Saturation or Lightness or Brightness, how do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: use `HSVColor` class

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use these helper methods to change it. Just replace

- `newHueValue`: with any double btw 0 and 360
- `newSaturationValue`: with any double btw 0 and 1
- `newLightnessValue`: with any double btw 0 and 1

```dart
Color changeColorHue(Color color) => HSLColor.fromColor(color).withHue(newHueValue).toColor();

Color changeColorSaturation(Color color) => HSLColor.fromColor(color).withSaturation(newSaturationValue).toColor();

Color changeColorLightness(Color color) => HSLColor.fromColor(color).withLightness(newLightnessValue).toColor();
```

Similarly you can use: `HSVColor` for HSV (hue, saturation, value).

more: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/HSLColor-class.html

Answer (score 3):

there are several ways of doing this

1.Most swatches have colors from 100 to 900 in increments of *one hundred*, plus the color 50. The smaller the number, the more pale the color. The greater the number, the darker the color. The accent swatches (e.g. `redAccent`) only have the values `100,` `200,` `400`, and `700`.

example `Color selection = Colors.green[400]; // Selects a mid-range green.`

sample color palette
[image: green palette]

In addition, a series of blacks and whites with common opacities are available. For example, black54 is a pure black with 54% opacity.

other methods of color are

`computeLuminance()` → double
    Returns a brightness value between 0 for darkest and 1 for lightest.

`toString() →` String
    Returns a string representation of this object.

`withAlpha(int a)` → Color
    Returns a new color that matches this color with the alpha channel replaced with a (which ranges from 0 to 255).

`withBlue(int b) →` Color
    Returns a new color that matches this color with the blue channel replaced with b (which ranges from 0 to 255).

`withGreen(int g)` → Color
    Returns a new color that matches this color with the green channel replaced with g (which ranges from 0 to 255).

`withOpacity(double opacity) →` Color
    Returns a new color that matches this color with the alpha channel replaced with the given opacity (which ranges from 0.0 to 1.0).

`withRed(int r)` → Color
    Returns a new color that matches this color with the red channel replaced with r (which ranges from 0 to 255).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tomas Barans answer:

Here are some relative helper methods to modify the saturation, hue and brightness without the need to set an absolute value:

```
Color increaseColorSaturation(Color color, double increment) {
  var hslColor = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  var newValue = min(max(hslColor.saturation + increment, 0.0), 1.0);
  return hslColor.withSaturation(newValue).toColor();
}

Color increaseColorLightness(Color color, double increment) {
  var hslColor = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  var newValue = min(max(hslColor.lightness + increment, 0.0), 1.0);
  return hslColor.withLightness(newValue).toColor();
}

Color increaseColorHue(Color color, double increment) {
  var hslColor = HSLColor.fromColor(color);
  var newValue = min(max(hslColor.lightness + increment, 0.0), 360.0);
  return hslColor.withHue(newValue).toColor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension method can also be used:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

extension ColorWithHSL on Color {
  HSLColor get hsl => HSLColor.fromColor(this);

  Color withSaturation(double saturation) {
    return hsl.withSaturation(clampDouble(saturation, 0.0, 1.0)).toColor();
  }

  Color withLightness(double lightness) {
    return hsl.withLightness(clampDouble(lightness, 0.0, 1.0)).toColor();
  }

  Color withHue(double hue) {
    return hsl.withHue(clampDouble(hue, 0.0, 360.0)).toColor();
  }
}
```